# Extremely suspicious phone call -- what to do?

Tags: incident-response, phone

Two days ago, I received a call.  Someone with a female, possibly asian voice asked "are you using your computer in internet right now."  I said "yes", then asked "who are you?".  At this point, they broke off the connection.  The way the connection broke sounded similar to what I heard on another [totally unrelated] occasion in life where I'm sure it was deliberate.

I'm not sure what to make of this, but I'm certain I don't like it.  Someone is trying to connect my online identity with my real-world identity (which would not be too hard; I typically use my real name, which is unique.)  Furthermore, they don't want me to know that they are doing that.  I have done some things that might make me unpopular in with certain groups.

What would it be sensible for me to do at this point?

Comment: Your second paragraph is entirely speculation. Closing as not a real quesiton

Comment: Cold call fake antivirus scam?

Comment: Yep, sounds like the fake AV call scam.

Comment: But it could also be any kind of telesales droid - most that call me these days hang up when I ask who they are calling on behalf of.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing. It could have been a survey to get information on internet usage, or a prank. Forget about it as it means nothing anyway: who isn't using their computer to access the internet?